# Filters and Convergence

Tags: general-topology

Show that ($\mathit{X}, \mathcal{T}_p$) -point chosen- is unique convergence except for the constant succession p (Where $\mathcal{T}_p$ is the point topology including).

I've been reading an example where $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $p = 1$ , then the sequence constant $\{1\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$converges to $1$ but also to all real numbers.

Comment: How is $\mathcal{T}_p$ defined? I am unfamiliar with the phrase "point topology inducing."

Comment: your definition in the comment is blunder, can you correct it. You should add the correct definition to the post

Comment: Tp = $\{U∈P(X):p\in U ∨ U=\emptyset\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it’s not what you described in your comment, I think that you mean the [particular point topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology): $\mathscr{T}_p=\{U\subseteq X:p\in U\text{ or }U=\varnothing\}$.

Now suppose that $x$ and $y$ are distinct points of $X\setminus\{p\}$, and that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $X$ converges both to $x$ and to $y$. The set $\{x,p\}$ is an open nbhd of $x$, so there is an $m_x\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in\{x,p\}$ for all $n\ge m_x$. Similarly, $\{y,p\}$ is an open nbhd of $y$, so there is an $m_y\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in\{y,p\}$ for all $n\ge m_y$. Let $m=\max\{m_x,m_y\}$; then for all $n\ge m$ we have

$$x_n\in\{x,p\}\cap\{y,p\}=\{p\}\;,$$

i.e., $x_n=p$ for all $n\ge m$. Thus, the only sequences in $X$ that converge to more than one point are the sequences that are eventually constant at $p$: every term from some point on is $p$.

And those sequences converge to every point of $X$. To see this, let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a sequence in $X$, and suppose that there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=p$ for each $n\ge m$. Let $x$ be any point of $X$, and let $U$ be any open nbhd of $x$. Then for each $n\ge m$ we have $x_n=p\in U$, so $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$. In particular, the constant sequence $\langle p,p,p,\ldots\rangle$ converges to every point of $X$.

Comment: What's the meaning of "nbhd"?

Comment: @Alex: It's short for *neighborhood*.